# Big O Dont understand how code is O(log n)

Tags: java, big-o

Hi im struggling to understand how this code snippet apprantley it is O(log n)?

```
 public void method(int n) {
        int i = 1; O(1)
        while(i < n) { - O(N)
            i = i * 2; - O(1)
            instruction(); - O(1)

        }

    }
```

The way i calculated it is instruction should just be O(1)
i = i * 2 should be O(1)?
And the while loop is where i get stuck i have it as O(n)
Meaning the whole thing is O(n)

Where im i getting confused here?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `while(i < n) { - O(N)` - that is not how anything works. You simply won't execute that line n times since i doubles on every iteration.

Comment: It can be helpful to print the iterations of the loop for different values of `n`. That way you can see what actually happens and why it doesn't take `O(n)`.

Comment: If the loop executes L times for some `n`, how many times does the loop execute for `2*n`?

Comment: @Turamarth ah so when i run it and say n = 5 the values of i are 1,2,4,8 so it does it 4 times not 5. Im not sure how that means its log?

Comment: Hi, maybe you should have a recap on how computing the algorith cost works. Here a good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6xkbGLQesk

Comment: Although an interesting question, it's not suitable for SO which about is how to do something in code. This is about understanding a computer science concept.

Comment: @jackjack100 `O(log n)` does not mean its literally `log n`. It just means its part of the family of functions that are bound by `k * log n` (for some constant `k`) when approaching infinity (so for large `n`s). It doesnt tell anything that you can just interpret simply by plugging in values. It is about asymptotic complexity. You should seriously recap Big-O in a more formal way that includes studying its mathematical definition.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration you double your `i`. Eventually it will be equal to 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2... and so on. It will repeat until `n` is greater than the result of such multiplication.

It means that `n` in that case will be roughly equal to `2^x`, where `x` is the number of iterations. `x` is the exponent), hence, the number of iterations equals *log, base 2, of n*.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how often the loop is executed it is helpful to test it for several values of `n` and see how the number of loops changes.

```
int i = 1;
while(i < n) {
    System.out.println(i);            
    i = i * 2;
}
```

I have added a print command to output the value of `i` before it is doubled.
Output for different values of `n`:

n = 2

```
1
```

n = 4

```
1
2
```

n = 8

```
1
2
4
```

n = 16

```
1
2
4
8
```

n = 32

```
1
2
4
8
16
```

n = 64

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
```

As you can see the loop only runs log2 of `n` times. For `n = 32` for example the loop runs only 5 times.
Since `i` is doubled after each iteration it will reach a value greater or equal to `n` in log2 of `n` steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void method(int n) {
    int i = 1; O(1)
    while(i < n) { - O(N) => No, you can't say O(N) by just looking at this line
        i = i * 2; - O(1)
        instruction(); - O(1)

    }

}
```

What exactly are asymptotic notations? They tell you the worst running complexity of your program / snippet. In this case, if you visualise,

- Number of times your while loop runs depends upon value of 'n'. So, total number of iteration is definitely a function of 'n'.
- Every time you are doubling the value of i. Which signifies, you are actually reducing the total number of iterations by half every time.

Lets count, say you have n = 100.

Assuming that we are printing the value of i at the end ofeach iteration,

2
4
8
16
32
64
128 => Terminating condition met

If you look closely, you can see number of iterations are now similar to logarithm function of 'n'.